How does $[\nabla_a\omega_b]_p$ depend on value of dual vector field $\omega_b$ in neighborhood of $p$?
Apologies in advance if this is a trivial/obvious question, but I'm not able to figure this out. I'm reading Differential Geometry by Liang; the book uses abstract index notation. It mentions at a point that if $\omega_b$ is a smooth dual vector field on a smooth manifold $M$, then $[\nabla_a\omega_b]_p$ depends on values of $\omega_b$ in a neighborhood of $p$.

Edit: Adding this section to add some context for the calculations after this section. There's a theorem that goes like so: Let $\omega_b,\omega'_b$ be dual vector fields such that $\omega_b|_p=\omega'_b|_p$.
I'm reproducing a calculation that's used in the proof: suppose $\Omega_b\equiv \omega'_b-\omega_b$. Choose a coordinate system $\{x^{\mu}\}$ such that its coordinate patch includes $p$, then $\Omega_{\mu}(p)=0$ for coordinate components $\Omega_{\mu}$ of $\Omega_b$. Hence at $p$ we have
$$[\nabla_a(\omega'_b-\omega_b)]_p=[\nabla_a\Omega_b]_p=\{\nabla_a[\Omega_{\mu}(dx^{\mu})_b]\}|_p$$
$$=\Omega_{\mu}(p)[\nabla_a(dx^{\mu})_b]_p+[(dx^{\mu})_b\nabla_a\Omega_{\mu}]_p\tag{1}$$

Choosing an arbitrary coordinate system $(U,x)$ containing $p$, I can write
$$[\nabla_a\omega_b]_p=[\nabla_a\big(\omega_{\mu}(dx^{\mu})_b\big)]_p=\omega_{\mu}(p)[\nabla_a(dx^{\mu})_b]_p+[(dx^{\mu})_b(d\omega_{\mu})_a]_p\tag{2}$$
where I've used $\nabla_a\omega_{\mu}=(d\omega_{\mu})_a$ since $\nabla_af=(df)_a$ for any smooth function $f$. The first term on the RHS only involves value of coordinates of $\omega_b$ at exactly the point $p$. So the dependency on $\omega_b$'s values around $p$ must be coming from the second RHS term. But I can't understand how? I can think of this analogy: derivative of a function evaluated at a point still depends on its values in the neighborhood of that point, but that picture is easy to understand intuitively.
Is there a way to intuitively understand how exactly the second RHS term depends on $\omega_b$'s values around $p$?

What you can write there is incomprehensible. Why is the covariant derivative of a one-form (dual vector field) equal to the exterior derivative? Liang cannot claim such nonsense. We know that the components satisfy: $\nabla_\alpha\omega_\mu=\partial_\alpha\omega_\mu-\Gamma^\nu_{\alpha\mu}\omega_\nu,.$ I  recommend the book by Sean Carroll to you in which no one is made to believe that DG and GR can only be formulated with abstract index notation. I do not even think that Liang & Zhou claim that.

@KurtG. Maybe I've made an error? Let me double-check and edit the question accordingly

Hi @KurtG., I've edited the question to include a section that's taken directly from the book. The calculation in eq. (2) mirrors that for eq. (1), unless I've missed something. Maybe I've made an error that's leading to the nonsense result as you mentioned..

On what page of the book is that?

@KurtG. It's on page 70 (Theorem 3.1.2)

I think I got it. Let me rewrite Liang's proof in component index notation.

$\boldsymbol{\Omega}=\Omega_\mu\,dx^\mu$ is a one-form that vanishes at $p\,.$ That is: $\Omega_\mu(p)=0$ for all $\mu\,.$

Then
$$\tag1\nabla_\nu\boldsymbol{\Omega}=(\nabla_\nu\Omega_\mu)\,dx^\mu+\Omega_\mu\nabla_\nu(dx^\mu)\,.$$

If you want you can write $\nabla_\nu(dx^\mu)$ in terms of Christoffel symbols as
$-\Gamma^\mu_{\rho\nu}\,dx^\rho\,.$ But we already know that this term will vanish at $p$ because it has the factor $\Omega_\mu(p)\,.$

$\nabla_\nu$ is the usual short notation for $\nabla_{\partial_\nu}$.
Since it is enough to define the connection on a basis the set of all $\nabla_\nu$ represents the connection, or, as you call it the "total covariant derivative."

If the manifold $M$ were just $\mathbb R^n$ (with some affine connection $\nabla$) then the term $\nabla_\nu\Omega_\mu$ would be the ordinary partial derivative $\partial_\nu\Omega_\mu$ since in that term $\Omega_\mu$ is a scalar, or as Liang & Zhou call it, a $(0,0)$ tensor.

That $\Omega_\mu$ is a $(0,0)$ tensor allows the authors to conclude  that $\nabla_\nu\Omega_\mu=d\Omega_\mu$ which does not depend on the connection.

In short: Liang & Zhou show no less and no more than, at $p\,,$
$\nabla_\nu\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ does not depend on the specific choice of $\nabla$ since only the first term in (1) survives. Their method of using abstract index notation is only another way of writing all this.



Thanks! How did we get to the first term in eq. (1) in your answer? So $(dx^{\mu})b\nabla_a\Omega{\mu}$ is the surviving RHS term in abstract index notation. Also note that LHS in eq. (1) in my question is the total covariant derivative of the dual vector field $\Omega$, i.e. $\nabla\Omega$. I think that the LHS in your eq. (1) is not the total covariant derivative - it's actually the covariant derivative operator (derivation) $\mathcal{T}^r_s\to\mathcal{T}^r_s$. That's why I'm not sure how $(dx^{\mu})b\nabla_a\Omega{\mu}$ directly translates to $\Omega_{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}(dx^{\mu})$

@Shirish I have updated the answer to address those questions. Please let it sink in.
